# What is the correct "healthy" adjective for healthy foods?

Tags: translation, adjectives

The situation is that I've expressed that I like Sushi, and then want to proceed and explain why that is, describing sushi as delicious and *healthy*. Something along the lines of:

> すしはおいしくて*ヘルシー*ですから。

Now I don't think ヘルシー or 元気 are probably the right choices here. It is also, that the fish itself is not healthy (it's usually just pretty dead when eating it), but it's good for the one eating the fish, that will get the health benefits.

This might be a trivial translation, but I'd be interested to see how I could find the correct answer myself, as a dictionary search on [jisho](http://jisho.org/) showed me interesting new vocabulary, but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Just to note that what you're looking for is akin to "healthy" vs. "healthful" in English, and a *large* percentage of English speakers incorrectly use the former when they really mean the latter.  AND IT DRIVES ME NUTS!!!

Comment: Your sentence 「(すしは)おいしくてヘルシーですから。」 sounds okay to me. I think it's fine to use the word ヘルシー for すし, as well as for other foods. You could also say 「おいしくてorおいしいし、ヘルシーですから(ね)。」「おいしくてorおいしいし、ヘルシーだから(ね)。(casual)」「・・・、ヘルシーなので。」「・・・、‌​ヘルシーですもんね。」etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word you're looking for is 体にいい (literally: *good for your body* in other words <s>healthy</s> healthful).

> 寿司は美味しいし体にもいいからかなり好きよ。
>   Sushi is delicious and it's even good for your health. I quite like it, you know.

I would not vouch for the naturalness of my example sentence but that's the idea.

Comment: Great answer, 100% natural. (Sushi Police certified)

Comment: Dear God! How come that a mini-anime from last season was called Sushi Police!?